# Setting ENV variable in groovy and retreiving it in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am setting environment variable `BRANCH_NAME_test` in my Groovy script, which I then call in my scripted pipeline, I would like to use ENV variable set in the groovy script in the pipeline but `echo "${env.BRANCH_NAME_test}"` returns null.

**Setting of the env variable in groovy script:**

```
environment { 
    def BRANCH_NAME_test = "branch"
}
```

**Pipeline:**

```
node () {  
  script {
    echo "${env.BRANCH_NAME_test}"
  }    
}
```

Comment: Are these two separate pipelines? Variables cannot be shared like this in such cases.